# How can I change the current window title with C?

Tags: c, linux, java-native-interface, terminal-emulator

I'm doing a homework which consists on calling several native functions of the C language from Java with JNI. 
One of the homework assingments is to change the current terminal title to whatever the user wants.
I have researched but I can't accomplish this on Linux :(.
I have tried using this:

```
printf("%c]0;%s%c", '\033', "My Console Title", '\007');
```

But it didn't work :(.
Any solutions?

Comment: What terminal client are you using? Not all terminals support window title changing.

Comment: gnome-terminal, I'm working on elementaryOS, @duskwuff